# How to expand a control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I've got a UserControl which has a grid, whose specification is as follows:

```
<Grid Name="fieldsGrid" Margin="15,0,0,10">
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

The second column is the one of interest.  It displays a checkbox, whose text is contained in a TextBlock and appears as `"Text..."` if it is too long.  This is accomplished through code-behind (I have my reasons) like so:

```
CheckBox currentCheckbox = new CheckBox();
TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
block.MaxWidth = 100;
block.Text = text;
block.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
block.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis;
currentCheckbox.Content = block;
currentCheckbox.ToolTip = metaText;
currentCheckbox.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
currentCheckbox.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
currentCheckbox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 10, 0);
currentCheckbox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
fieldsGrid.Children.Add(currentCheckbox);
```

The problem is that I want to expand this checkbox as the UserControl is resized, thus showing more text as the size increases.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: `This is accomplished through code-behind (I have my reasons)` - I seriously doubt you have valid reasons for such a horrible mess. In WPF, XAML is used to create the UI. Period.

Comment: Well since you asked @HighCore - they're not reasons as such, rather I'm working on someone else's code and I cannot change it too much. So I unfortunately have to make do with what I've got :/

Comment: I hear you... I found out that it ended up being easier to completely refactor a badly implemented WPF UI the RIGHT way, that trying to get something decent out of these winforms developers' hacks.

Comment: I agree with you, but modifying it could get me into trouble hehe so it's easier to suffer in silence @HighCore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this and thus remove code-behind?

```
<Grid Name="fieldsGrid"
      Margin="15,0,0,10">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <CheckBox Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0 10 10 0">
    <CheckBox.Content>
      <!--  Make a binding for the Text of TextBlock below  -->
      <TextBlock MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                   AncestorType={x:Type CheckBox}}}"
                 Text="Some Text LOng FFFFFFF DDDDDDDDDDDD"
                 TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                 TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
    </CheckBox.Content>
  </CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

That should give you the behavior your looking for and does everything your code-behind does(You need to sort the binding for text to the `TextBlock` ofc)

**On OP's particular request** (Code-Behind to be avoided if it can be):

Can add with the code-behind you got (at the end)

```
currentCheckbox.SizeChanged += (sender, args) => block.MaxWidth = args.NewSize.Width;  // Subtract the checkbox indicator width from args.NewSize.Width here for accurate TextBlock Width measurement
```

[Video Link](http://www.speedyshare.com/HHbZK/sample.avi)

Comment: As I mentioned above in the comments, this is someone else's code and I have to leave it as it is, aside from fixing this problem :/ Could you adopt the solution for code behind?

Comment: I've added an edit that should do it if you got a constraint to use code-behind

Comment: It seems to work, however on reducing the size after it has been increased, the text's max width is not set to a smaller size. How can this be done from the code you provided at the bottom of the answer?

Comment: In other words, on increasing the window's size, the checkbox's text is increased too. But when i decide to decrease the window's size after doing that, it doesnt do the opposite.

Comment: err it does fine for me on increasing / decreasing window size to change checkbox dimensions. I'll post a video link if i can find a capture tool

Comment: What I mean is that it only seems to work for increasing, but not decreasing.

Comment: I've added a video link at the bottom. Is that not what your seeing when re-sizing (Increase OR Decrease) the Window?

Comment: No, that's unfortunately not what I'm seeing. It only works on increasing, but not decreasing :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28274/discussion-between-viv-and-dot-net)

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to work for me. I used XAML just to define the CheckBox and the TextBlock containing it's label content, like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="603.433" Width="730.97">
    <Grid Name="fieldsGrid"
      Margin="15,0,0,10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Column 1"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Column 3, a bit bigger"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="0" x:Name="txtWidth"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="Column 5, really really really big"></TextBlock>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="testChk"
            Margin="0 10 10 0">
            <CheckBox.Content>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtForCheckBox"></TextBlock>
            </CheckBox.Content>
        </CheckBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then code-behind looks like this:

public MainWindow()
    {

```
    InitializeComponent();
    testChk.SizeChanged += testChk_SizeChanged;

    txtForCheckBox.Text = "Some text, test, test, test.";
    txtForCheckBox.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis;
    txtForCheckBox.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
}

void testChk_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    txtForCheckBox.MaxWidth = testChk.ActualWidth;
    txtWidth.Text = testChk.ActualWidth.ToString();
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: No luck with this. I'm suspecting that it has something to do with some code in the code behind.

Comment: What happens? I'm curious :)

Comment: Tune in on the chatroom which Viv invited me to above, he's helping me solve the issue :)